# FFMPEG image + music = video

Tags: ffmpeg

Just trying todo video for youtube from image (1080p .png) + music (320Kb mp3).

```
    ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.png -i music.mp3 -c:a copy -c:v libx264 -crf 0 -preset veryslow -shortest output.mp4
```

But converting is to slowly.
Any ideas, how it make optimize?

`E:_TEST>ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image0.png -i music0.mp3 -c:a aac -c:v libx264 -crf 0 -preset veryfast -shortest video0.mp4
    ffmpeg version N-87306-g6743351 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
    built with gcc 7.2.0 (GCC)
    configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib
    libavutil            55. 75.100 / 55. 75.100
    libavcodec         57.106.101 / 57.106.101
    libavformat        57. 82.100 / 57. 82.100
    libavdevice        57.    8.101 / 57.    8.101
    libavfilter         6.105.100 /    6.105.100
    libswscale            4.    7.103 /    4.    7.103
    libswresample     2.    8.100 /    2.    8.100
    libpostproc        54.    6.100 / 54.    6.100
    Input #0, png_pipe, from 'image0.png':
    Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
        Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgb24(pc), 1920x1080, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
    Input #1, mp3, from 'music0.mp3':
    Metadata:
        encoder                 : Lavf57.56.101
    Duration: 01:00:33.06, start: 0.025057, bitrate: 128 kb/s
        Stream #1:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 kb/s
        Metadata:
            encoder                 : Lavc57.64
    Stream mapping:
    Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (png (native) -> h264 (libx264))
    Stream #1:0 -> #0:1 (mp3 (native) -> aac (native))
    Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
    [libx264 @ 0000000002d3f320] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX XOP FMA3 BMI1
    [libx264 @ 0000000002d3f320] profile High 4:4:4 Predictive, level 4.0, 4:4:4 8-bit
    [libx264 @ 0000000002d3f320] 264 - core 152 r2851 ba24899 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2017 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=1 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x1:0x111 me=hex subme=2 psy=0 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=0 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=0 chroma_qp_offset=0 threads=12 lookahead_threads=4 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=1 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc=cqp mbtree=0 qp=0
    Output #0, mp4, to 'video0.mp4':
    Metadata:
        encoder                 : Lavf57.82.100
        Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv444p(progressive), 1920x1080, q=-1--1, 25 fps, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc
        Metadata:
            encoder                 : Lavc57.106.101 libx264
        Side data:
            cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
        Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
        Metadata:
            encoder                 : Lavc57.106.101 aac
    frame=    107 fps= 40 q=-1.0 Lsize=         778kB time=00:00:04.24 bitrate=1503.5kbits/s speed=1.57x`

Comment: Can you also post the contents of your _veryslow_ preset file? What is the size of the file you are attempting to convert?

Comment: Have you at least read a description of used tag? Interactive usage is offtopic to SO. Ask your question [here](https://superuser.com/)

Comment: @MattClark There are no external preset files. The presets are integrated within x264.

Comment: Hi, is it good?
https://pastebin.com/jD3kF2DA

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 1 -i image.png -i music.mp3 -c:v libx264 -crf 0 -preset veryfast -tune stillimage -c:a copy -shortest output.mkv
```

- Uses a frame rate of 1.
- Just muxes the audio and avoids re-encoding the audio.
- Uses Matroska output format instead of MP4 to handle almost any audio format.

The output may not work in some players but it will work fine in YouTube.

Comment: Yeap, that was helped. Thanks!

Comment: @drgs "The output may not work in some players but it will work fine in YouTube." The question asked for a solution for YouTube. If you want it to work in a standard player then use `-framerate 25`, `-crf 18`, `-c:a aac`, `output.mp4` instead.

Comment: I tried a million of the combinations by trial and error, this one worked for me: ffmpeg -r 1 -loop 1 -i image.png -i music.mp3 -acodec copy -r 1 -tune stillimage -shortest video.flv

Answer (score 0):

ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.png -i music.mp3 -c:a aac -c:v libx264 -crf 0 -preset veryfast -shortest output.mp4

That will be faster.